# Google Charts with PHP auto Refresh the Chart

Tags: javascript, php, dashboard

Hi all I am struggling to auto-refresh the google charts i.e Line,Pie, Column and Bar chart etc. after a set interval say 5 secs or something. I have tried the below but it ends up loading an empty page with no content rather than the chart being refreshed:

This is pieChart.php for instance

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
    $("#pieChart").load('pieContent.php')
     }, 2000);
   });

 </script>
```

The pieContent.php files looks something like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>






 <script type="text/javascript">
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2);
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(draw2);
 var visualization;


    function draw2() {
      drawVisualization();
      drawToolbar();
    }
    function drawVisualization() {
     var container = document.getElementById('visualization_div');
     visualization = new google.visualization.PieChart(container);
     new google.visualization.Query('https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=pCQbetd-CptHnwJEfo8tALA').
         send(queryCallback);
   }


 function drawChart2() {

 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
 ['Users', 'Safety Status'],
 <?php

$site2="Test Site";

    $query = "SELECT count(Event_Name) AS count, Event_Name FROM Event_History WHERE SiteID='$site2' GROUP BY Event_Name ";


 $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

 echo "['".$row['Event_Name']."',".$row['count']."],";
 }
 ?>
 ]);

 var options = {
 title: 'Event Statistics'
 };

 var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart2'));

 function selectHandler() {
         var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
         if (selectedItem) {
           var topping = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);

           var selected = topping;
        alert("You have selected the " +topping + " Portion in Pie Chart");
          var myval = "this is a php variable"; // generated by PHP

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'eventStats.php',
            data: {'variable': myval},
          });

         }
       }
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);

 chart.draw(data, options);
 }
 function drawToolbar() {
    var components = [
        {type: 'igoogle', datasource: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=pCQbetd-CptHnwJEfo8tALA',
         gadget: 'https://www.google.com/ig/modules/pie-chart.xml',
         userprefs: {'3d': 1}},
        {type: 'html', datasource: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=pCQbetd-CptHnwJEfo8tALA'},
        {type: 'csv', datasource: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=pCQbetd-CptHnwJEfo8tALA'},
        {type: 'htmlcode', datasource: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=pCQbetd-CptHnwJEfo8tALA',
         gadget: 'https://www.google.com/ig/modules/pie-chart.xml',
         userprefs: {'3d': 1},
         style: 'width: 800px; height: 700px; border: 3px solid purple;'}
    ];

    var container = document.getElementById('toolbar_div');
    google.visualization.drawToolbar(container, components);
  };
 </script>


</head>
<body>
  <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
            <div id="piechart2" style="width: 700px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

However Unfortunetely this does not work and loads bland page. Where as if i open pieContent.php directly it open the pie chart. Any solutions..

Comment: user reload page as .reload() function jquery

Comment: Lomnesh Kelwadar I know I can reload the whole page every 5 or 10 secs but this will cause the entire page to flicker and refresh every x secs which is something I don't want. I just want to refresh the div holding the google pie chart rather than the entire table.